# Странное поведение кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся со странной проблемой. При попытке запуска кода приведенного ниже, вылетает ошибка: (IndexError: list index out of range). Но стоит в списке a и списке b заменить элемент 'КС 7-1' например на 'КС 7-1 ' или на любое другое значение, то код начинает работать исправно. Заранее благодарен за помощь в решении данного вопроса.

Краткое описание принципа работы кода:
Программа поэлементно сравнивает значения из списка b с элементами списка a (каждый с каждым), при определении совпадения записывает значение из списка с в список d при отсутствии совпадения в список d записывается '-'. На выходе получается список из 16 элементов. В примере на выходе получается список:

```
d = [['1', '-', '-', '2', '-', '-', '1', '-', '-', '1', '-', '-', '-', '1', '2', '-', '-']]
```

---

```
a = ['ПН 10','ПН 15','ПН 20','КС 10-9','КС 15-9',
     'КС 20-9','ПП 10','ПП 15','ПП 20','КС 7-9','КС 7-6',
     'КС 7-3','КС 7-1.5','КС 7-1','КО 6','К1-А','ОП-1К']

b = [['ПН 10','КС 10-9','ПП 10','КС 7-9','КС 7-1','КО 6']]

c = [['1','2','1','1','1','2']]
    
d = [[] for x in range(len(b))]

j = 0

def contains_elem(item, construction_list):
    for elem in construction_list:
        if item.find(elem) != -1:
            return True
    return False

for i in range(len(b)):
    for item in a:
        if contains_elem(item, b[i]):
            d[i].append(str(c[i][j]))
            j += 1
        else:
            d[i].append("-")
    j = 0
print(d)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки с трейсбеком.

Comment: К сожалению пишу в Dynamo. Там довольно суровая IDE (даже строчки не подсвечивает, что там говорить про трейсбэки). Прикрепил скрин с онлайн отладчика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строковая операция `item.find` находит подстроку `КС 7-1` как в 'КС 7-1.5', так и в 'КС 7-1', поэтому `j` становится больше размеров списков `b[0]` и `c[0]`

Очевидно, что здесь логическая ошибка, но что именно нужно делать - зависит от вашей задачи.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за подсказку! Я бы еще неделю голову ломал в чем проблема. Теперь буду думать над решением!

Comment: Я добавил print(item, i, j) после contains_elem,  а то в списках тяжело было глазу зацепиться.

Comment: Решил проблему заменой item.find(elem) != -1: на  item == elem: Я не так давно программирую. В методах невероятное количество тонкостей. Еще раз благодарю за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
a = ['ПН 10','ПН 15','ПН 20','КС 10-9','КС 15-9',
     'КС 20-9','ПП 10','ПП 15','ПП 20','КС 7-9','КС 7-6',
     'КС 7-3','КС 7-1.5','КС 7-1','КО 6','К1-А','ОП-1К']

b = ['ПН 10','КС 10-9','ПП 10','КС 7-9','КС 7-1','КО 6']

c = ['1','2','1','1','1','2']
    
d = []

def contains_elem(item, construction_list):
    for elem in construction_list:
        if item.find(elem) != -1:
            return True
    return False

for i in range(len(b)):
    for item in a:
        if contains_elem(item, b):
            d.append(str(c[i]))
        else:
            d.append("-")
print(d)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Важно что бы списки b и c имели вложенность.  Но на всякий случай запустил данное решение в онлайн отладчике и количество итераций улетело за 1000. Код перестал выполнять необходимую функцию.